# Program failed: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am trying to implement a merkle distributor and am forking https://github.com/coral-xyz/merkle-distributor

If I set my solana version to 1.16.0 then anchor build and anchor deploy works fine. But running the create-distributor script gives me  'Program 5LcodVV79KmCvk26e5bWyGmhn6HBQKgthw6Sd7c9rPjD invoke [1]',
'Program log: Instruction: NewDistributor',
'Program 5LcodVV79KmCvk26e5bWyGmhn6HBQKgthw6Sd7c9rPjD consumed 10573 of 400000 compute units',
'Program 5LcodVV79KmCvk26e5bWyGmhn6HBQKgthw6Sd7c9rPjD failed: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933684 > 1280)'

If I downgrade Solana to 1.14.28 then my anchor build fails with this error error[E0425]: cannot find function `is` in this scope
--> src/lib.rs:98:6
|
98 |     !is(stream)
|      ^^ not found in this scope

Compiling cc v1.0.73
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `atty` due to previous error

Would greatly appreciate any help.